# In the JVMS, what is the ClassSignature for java.lang.Object, given that SuperclassSignature is non-optional?

Tags: jvm, specifications

Section [4.7.9.1 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1) concerns signatures. One of the kinds of signatures is a [`ClassSignature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-ClassSignature).

The grammar involved in this production indicates that a `SuperclassSignature` is non-optional.

So what is the `ClassSignature` for Java's `java.lang.Object` class? Why is `SuperclassSignature` non-optional [in the `ClassSignature` production](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-ClassSignature)?

The only way I can see all of this working is if `Identifier` can be the empty string.

Comment: There is none. `java.lang.Object` can’t be generic.

Comment: Thanks; I understand that. The spec says: "A class signature encodes type information about a (possibly generic) class or interface declaration." Note the "possibly" part, which is part of why I'm asking.

Comment: A class doesn’t have to be generic, to have a signature attribute. Having a parameterized superclass or implementing a parameterized interface would qualify as well. But neither applies to `java.lang.Object`. It doesn’t seem to be specified explicitly, though. But it’s simply impossible to change `java.lang.Object` in that regard and produce a valid class file.

Comment: Thank you. So somewhere, presumably, in the compiler code, there is something that writes `ClassSignatures` and that will never "fire" when supplied "`java.lang.Object`" (you see what I'm saying). Interesting. Actually I see now also that the production also makes `SuperinterfaceSignature` non-optional (it's one or more), so there are a variety of ways to ask my question, I guess. Surely not every `ClassSignature` has superinterfaces? and yet that's also what the grammar implies. How interesting.

Comment: I tried with Java 8’s `javac` and it simply crashed while trying to write the generic signature. Doesn’t look like the compiler authors added specific code to prevent you from doing so, only the code producing the signature was designed in such a way that producing an invalid signature (in this regard) is impossible. The section refers to [§4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.1) which says “*The syntax {x} on the right-hand side of a production denotes **zero or more occurrences** of x.*”

Comment: Good grief; dyslexia or something for the win. Thanks. Another way to ask my question would be: what is the `ClassSignature` for an interface `Foo<T>`, although I suppose in that case the `SuperclassSignature` would be that of `java.lang.Object`. That's why I picked `java.lang.Object` in my thought experiment above.

Comment: Yes, when I use `jdk-17\bin\javap -v java.util.List`, it prints `Signature: #206                         // <E:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Collection<TE;>;` so `<E:Ljava/lang/Object;>` is the type variable `E`, `Ljava/lang/Object;` the superclass, and `Ljava/util/Collection<TE;>;` the superinterface.